# Insert a Row inside a Column in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My UI screen is basically rendered using a Column Widget and inside this widget, I am inserting all the other UI components. One of these happens to be a Row ( consisting of 2 text fields). This is the Row Widget :

```
var phoneNumber = new Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: countryCodePicker,
    ),
    new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: mobileNumber,
    ),
  ],
);
```

The Main UI Screen being :

```
     return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
                customerName,
                emailAddress,
//                new Container(
//                  child: deliveryOptionRow,
//                ),
                mobileNumber,
                countryCodePicker,
                templateMessagesDropDown,
                templateMessageTextField,
                sendGoogleReview,
              ],
            )
    );
```

I see this exception when I add the Row to the Column

```
     The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
flutter:   _RenderListTile#06b03 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:   creator: _ListTile ← MediaQuery ← Padding ← SafeArea ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
flutter:   RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← InkWell ← ListTile ← ListTileTheme ← ⋯
flutter:   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
flutter:   constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
flutter:   size: MISSING
flutter: This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
flutter:   _RenderRadio#302a4 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:   RenderParagraph#58a45 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
```

What would be the best way to add the row inside the main UI screen.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

this should solve your problem,

```
var phoneNumber = new Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: countryCodePicker,
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: mobileNumber,
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

hope it helps!

Comment: awesome thanks a ton. I did not realise that I had to place the Row sub widgets inside the Expanded instead of the entire Row.

Comment: I don't understand why this works when the original code didn't. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Expanded in Row is useless when we have 2 children widgets in a row. It divides equal width to both 2 children widgets while both children widgets should be aligned left without any unnecessary blank space. any other suggestion except Expanded and Fixed Width? Kindly share your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 56):

If your `Row` contains a `TextField` or `TextFormField` or any other widget which tries to grow to infinity, you need to provide an intrinsic width to it. You can do it in several ways:

- Use **`Expanded`**:

  ```dart
  Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: TextField(), // <-- Wrapped in Expanded.
      ),
    ],
  )
  ```
- Use **`Flexible`**:

  ```dart
  Row(
    children: [
      Flexible(
        child: TextField(), // <-- Wrapped in Flexible.
      ),
    ],
  )
  ```
- Provide a **fixed width**:

  ```dart
  Row(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        width: 200, // <-- Fixed width.
        child: TextField(),
      ),
    ],
  )
  ```

Comment: imo, this should have been the best answer. for the provided explaination.